# Cordova/Ionic: Can the client see whats in my plugins/ and bower_components/ folders when I release my app?

Tags: cordova, security, ionic-framework, minify, directory-structure

I'm a noob to hybrid (and web) development and have a question on securing your mobile app. And yes I did consider posting this on https://security.stackexchange.com/ however my question is spit on file structure, minification, using modules and the compiling process.

Obviously, you should hide your apps secret keys server side. That being said, I've seen modules that store keys in both the `plugins/` and `bower_components/` folders. That cannot be safe however from what I've seen when I opened my apps `.api` and `.apk` files I can only see what is in the `www/` folder.

So my questions are:

**1. what happens to the `plugins/` and `bower_components/` folders?**

My best guess is they are they compiled into machine code but it's still not secure as the keys themselves are on the client side, so why am I seeing modules that do this like?

**2. And even if you do store your secret keys server side how is minification of your `.js` files enough?**

Couldn't someone put the `www/` folder into new ionic app and use the development tools to check incoming and outgoing activities get your keys?

**3. Does HTML have vulnerability?**

Answer (score 0):

1. Nothing change for apk file; the directory struture will change for ipa file;
2. I suggest you use webpack,